# TypeError: buf.writeBigUInt64BE is not a function (it is undefined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use the following code on React Native iOS device:

```
import { Buffer } from "buffer";
const buf = Buffer.alloc(8)
buf.writeBigUInt64BE(BigInt(123), 0)
const value = buf.readBigUInt64BE(0)
console.log(value)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: buf.readBigUInt64BE is not a function (it is undefined)
```

This only happens for all `BigInt` functions. I've used `readIntBE`, `readUIntBE` and their LE and write equivalents and all work. Hovering over the function leads me to `buffer.d.ts` with the correct description.

My node version is v20.3.1 which should include the function. What could be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run `npm i buffer --legacy-peer-deps` for buffer version 6.0.3

Comment: You could also give a try to @vekexasia/bigint-buffer-polyfill for other methods in case you need.